# Good implementation of unit test with EasyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I have a question about good implementation of unit test with EasyMock.

First implementation:

```
Capture<String> capturedString = newCapture();
myService.doSomething(capture(capturedString));
expectLastCall();

assertEquals("stringValue", catpuredString.getValue());
```

Second implementation:

```
myService.doSomething("stringValue");
expectLastCall();
```

I feel comfortable with the first implementation because an assertion is present. But in the second implementation I expect "stringValue" passed to my service. If it's not the case an exception will be thrown by EasyMock. So is there a difference between the 2 implementations ? If not, is one better than the other ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GreenGiant's answer is quite good. Both ways are equivalent in result but have a different feeling. And btw, there's no need to add `expectLastCall()`. It's implicit on void methods.

To add to the answer:

An expectation is something you expect to happen. Something you care about. For instance, if you care about doSomething being called but you don't care about the parameter passed, you would use `any()` as a matcher. To show your intention (that you don't care). If the parameter does matter, the equals matcher make sense.

Then, indeed the capture is frequently used because your not quite sure what will be passed. For instance, if there is no `equals()` method defined on the object.

I tend to use the capture and a list of asserts when I have complex objects to check. If I have a bean with many fields, it is easier to have a list of asserts then to use a `cmpEq` matcher.

Then only drawback of this method is that you won't know right away that the parameter passed isn't valid. The tested method will continue to execute and might fail afterwards. So you will never reach your assertions and think the bug is farther in the code than it really is.

But is the tested code is nicely atomic and not too complicated, this shouldn't happen too much.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it just depends on whether you know the string value up-front, before you record your mock calls.

- If you already know the string value, then use the second implementation, because it's simpler.
- But if you don't know it ahead of time, then use the first implementation. For example, if the value passed into your service is dynamic and you don't know what it should be before you actually run your test.